# How to discover packages in special directory with Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create my own Laravel 5.5 Package, I put them in `/packages/myvendor/mypackage`. Is there any way to make Laravel Package Auto-Discovery seen my packages without adding `MyServiceProvider::class` to `config/app.php`?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this didn't understand the question. This question is perfectly valid and properly stated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution! I add my local packages to composer.json with

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "packages/vendor/package",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    ]
```

Then require my package with `composer require vendor/package:dev-master`. Then laravel will auto discover my package

Comment: This is great :-) The `"symlink": true` option will create a symbolic link from the root directory of your package under development, to the `vendor` directory of your application, in the correct `{vendor}/{pachage}` directory. Though not strictly needed for classes, some tools expect certain files to be in specific places (such as Laravel's package discovery features).

Answer (score 0):

This is from the official documentation. You have to set things in composer.json like this

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "Foo\\Bar\\ServiceProvider"
        ],
        "aliases": {
            "Bar": "Foo\\Bar\\Facade"
        }
    }
}
```

This will make your package auto discover. For more detailed description [here](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/package-auto-discovery-in-laravel-5-5-ea9e3ab20518) is the tylor's article on auto discovery in Laravel 5.5

Comment: I have already done this, but laravel don't auto recognize my package. I must add my provider to app config to recognize it. I also added my `src/` to main `composer.json`

Comment: did you try this php "artisan package:discover" ?

Comment: I tried both  `php artisan package:discover` `composer dump-autoload` `php artisan config:cache` but it still not see my package

Comment: check your laravel version through php artisan --version to ensure you really have version 5.5

Comment: `php artisan --version` -> Laravel framework 5.5.14 
I also run `composer update`

Comment: @Adamnick you misunderstood the question. The OP is developing their own package locally. Your solution will not be detected by the the root testing app where his package is being deployed because the app has no knowledge of the package's composer.json (which is where you suggest he make changes). As the OP eventually found out, he needs to add his package as a local "path" repository in his own composer.json, not the package's.